Refresh the page after form submit (Moodle) (Ionic5)
I wrote a plugin for Moodle. I have integrated this plugin into the app. Now I have the problem that when I submit a form I am redirected back to the original page and the page then automatically reloads.
Unfortunately I have no idea how to do the redirection and the page reload.
What would be the usual method?
According to the Moodle page, Ionic 5 is used.
So far I have no idea how to solve the problem and would be very happy to hear from you.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
